# Exception in JavaFX Application Thread

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I've been trying to make a GUI Media Player using JavaFX. Whenever i try to select a file the following error takes place.

**STACK-TRACE**

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$5(GtkApplication.java:139)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.161-5.b14.fc27.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/libjfxmedia.so
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1827)
at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryFullPath(NativeLibLoader.java:201)
at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryInternal(NativeLibLoader.java:94)
at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibLoader.java:39)
at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager.lambda$new$0(NativeMediaManager.java:115)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager.<init>(NativeMediaManager.java:106)
at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager$NativeMediaManagerInitializer.<clinit>(NativeMediaManager.java:77)
at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager.getDefaultInstance(NativeMediaManager.java:89)
at com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaManager.canPlayProtocol(MediaManager.java:78)
at com.sun.media.jfxmedia.locator.Locator.<init>(Locator.java:232)
at javafx.scene.media.Media.<init>(Media.java:393)
at application.SampleController.handleButtonAction(SampleController.java:37)
... 58 more
```

> I've been trying to make sense and i think my **SampleController.java** file is sort of messed up.

**SampleController.java**

```
package application;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable; 
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;

public class SampleController implements Initializable {

private String filePath;
@FXML
private MediaPlayer mp;
@FXML
private MediaView mv;
@Override
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {}

@FXML
public void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    FileChooser fc= new FileChooser();
    FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extensionFilter= new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Video files with mp4 extension only.", "*.mp4");
    fc.getExtensionFilters().add(extensionFilter);

    File file= fc.showOpenDialog(null);
    filePath= file.toURI().toString();
    if(filePath!= null) {
        Media media= new Media(filePath);
        mp= new MediaPlayer(media);
        mv.setMediaPlayer(mp);
        DoubleProperty width= mv.fitWidthProperty();
        DoubleProperty height= mv.fitHeightProperty();
        width.bind(Bindings.selectDouble(mv.sceneProperty(), "width"));
        height.bind(Bindings.selectDouble(mv.sceneProperty(), "height"));
        mp.play();
    }
}

@FXML public void playButton(ActionEvent event) {mp.play(); mp.setRate(1);}
@FXML public void pauseButton(ActionEvent event) {mp.pause();}
@FXML public void stopButton(ActionEvent event) {mp.stop();}
@FXML public void forwardButton(ActionEvent event) {}
@FXML public void rewindButton(ActionEvent event) {}
@FXML public void fasterButton(ActionEvent event) {mp.setRate(2);}
@FXML public void slowerButton(ActionEvent event) {mp.setRate(0.5);}
@FXML public void exitButton(ActionEvent event) {Platform.exit();}
}
```

> Line 37 in **SampleController.java** is
>
> ```
> Media media= new Media(filePath);
> ```
>
> **Few Notes**
>
> - There is no **libjfxmedia.so** file on my system.
> - I'm using EclipseIDE with JavaFX Extension installed.
> - OpenJDK version- 1.8.0_161

Comment: Take a look on this site [Oracle JDK 8 and JRE 8 Certified System Configurations
Contents](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/certconfig-2095354.html)  especially the part "JavaFX Media on Linux"

Comment: @Edwardth I'm using Fedora 27 64bit. Which i think is equivalent of RHEL 6.* . And table shows it's support. Could it be a missing software issue?

Comment: maybe you need to add libjfxmedia.so native?

Comment: @NikiforosArchakis How do i add it ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47718273/5165833

Comment: @NikiforosArchakis I have openjfx installed on my system. Also, I can't find any rpm or library for my os architecture :(. Links or advice would be appreciated