# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat(IIILjava/nio/ByteBuffer;)J

Tags: java, opencv, kotlin, gradle, javacv

I'm work on project using JavaFX and JavaCV. My main feature in app is based on webcam capture. I'm looking for a way to display frame from OpenCVFrameGrabber into JavaFX component.

I found a way to do it but I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat(IIILjava/nio/ByteBuffer;)J
    at org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat(Native Method)
    at org.opencv.core.Mat.<init>(Mat.java:52)
    at org.bytedeco.javacv.OpenCVFrameConverter.convertToOrgOpenCvCoreMat(OpenCVFrameConverter.java:187)
    at org.bytedeco.javacv.OpenCVFrameConverter$ToOrgOpenCvCoreMat.convert(OpenCVFrameConverter.java:61)
    at TestJavaCV$Companion.main(TestJavaCV.kt:20)
    at TestJavaCV.main(TestJavaCV.kt)
```

I suspect that the application is not working due to not dependency failure. Probably I should provide additional libs for **org.opencv.core** but I don't know how to achieve this in gradle.

**Minimal, Reproducible Example:**

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'javacv-platform', version: '1.5.3'
}
```

**TestJavaCV.kt**

```
import javafx.scene.image.Image
import org.bytedeco.javacv.Frame
import org.bytedeco.javacv.OpenCVFrameConverter
import org.bytedeco.javacv.OpenCVFrameGrabber
import org.opencv.core.Mat
import org.opencv.core.MatOfByte
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream

class TestJavaCV {
    companion object {
        private val toOrgOpenCvCoreMat = OpenCVFrameConverter.ToOrgOpenCvCoreMat()

        @JvmStatic
        fun main(args: Array<String>) {
            val grabber: OpenCVFrameGrabber = OpenCVFrameGrabber(0);
            grabber.start()

            val frame: Frame = grabber.grabFrame()
            val mat: Mat = toOrgOpenCvCoreMat.convert(frame)
            val matOfByte: MatOfByte = MatOfByte()

            Imgcodecs.imencode(".png", mat, matOfByte)
            val image = Image(ByteArrayInputStream(matOfByte.toArray()))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: UnsatisfiedLinkError usually means you are missing a driver, not a class.  It is likely the call to Mat.n_Mat() is to a native driver that is not available.  This probably is not a JAR, but more likely a missing DLL or SO.

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42569126/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-org-opencv-core-mat-n-matiiij - this is a very similar issue and shows how the driver is loaded.

Comment: I read your references. In project I have a requirement for the application to work on Windows 10, Linux and MacOS. I wonder if it is possible to use gradle instead of
providing the path to lib.

Comment: Another question: where is located openCV to use Load by path if I'm using gradle. ```System.load("my/full/path/native.dll");```

Comment: If openCV is installed on your system, you should have a DLL to reference.  You would need to check the openCV docs.  From the referenced question, they suggest this `System.load("fullPathTo/opencv.dll");` - you need to find out where opencv.dll is installed on your system.  "fullPathTo" is just a placeholder for the actual path.

Comment: Maybe this other question can help you:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17767557/how-to-use-opencv-in-using-gradle

Comment: BTW, it's easier to get this work with [Gradle JavaCPP](https://github.com/bytedeco/gradle-javacpp#getting-started). See https://github.com/bytedeco/gradle-javacpp/tree/master/samples/javacv-demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question [java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat(III)J?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42569126/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-org-opencv-core-mat-n-matiiij) answers why you are getting that `UnsatisfiedLinkError`; the library for OpenCV is not loaded by your Java VM and therefore the relevant native calls cannot be made.

This question [How to use opencv in using Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17767557/how-to-use-opencv-in-using-gradle) should help you with configuring OpenCV using Gradle.

Per your comment question "I have a requirement for the application to work on Windows 10, Linux and MacOS." I don't know how to solve that using gradle, however in Java I would inject a different system property per o/s and use that in a static block in your class to load your library:

```
static {

    String libraryPath = System.getProperty("opencv.path");

    System.load(libraryPath);

}
```

Comment: In the case of JavaCV, it's easier to just call `Loader.load(opencv_java.class)` as documented here: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/tree/master/opencv#documentation